# C# How to get the Enum value from ComboBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

I am binding a Dictionary to a ComboBox which keeps the Enum values.

To retrieve the selected value I used:
`comboBox1.SelectedItem` which returns a dimensional value of `[0,Permanent]`.

I just want to retrieve `Permanent` and then convert it back to Enum.

Something like:
`Employee.JobType = Enum.Parse(JobType, comboBox1.SelectedItem)`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi
Employee.JobType = (JobType)comboBox1.SelectedValue
try this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either:

```
Employee.JobType = (JobType)Enum.Parse(typeof(JobType), comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Or:

```
Employee.JobType = (JobType)Enum.Parse(typeof(JobType), comboBox1.SelectedText);
```

Comment: The first requires a .ToString() at the end.

Comment: I'll second Jack on that. The 2nd option works better.

Answer (score 1):

If items source for combo box is a dictionary, SelectedItem is of type: KeyValuePair<[type of key], JobType>

You can access your enum value by casting SelectedItem and accessing Value property.

```
var selectedItem = (KeyValuePair<[type of key], JobType>) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
var jobType = selectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: nice and clean solution tks

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick, I think:

```
string[] parts = comboBox1.SelectedItem.Split(
                      new char[] { ',', '[', ']' }, 
                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Employee.JobType = (JobType)Enum.Parse(typeof(JobType), parts[1].Trim()));
```

First, split up the string using comma and the square brackets, and have the method remove any empty elements. This should leave you with an array containing the number and the text. Use the text part for enum parsing.

Note that you need to pass the `Type` object for the enum into the `Parse` method, and then you need to cast the result, since the return type of `Parse` is `object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee.JobType = (JobTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(JobTypeEnum), comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this -- http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip4.asp

```
PeopleNames people = (PeopleNames)Enum.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, PeopleNames)
```

Data Binding:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(PeopleNames))
```

Comment: The referenced article is very good. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - (WPF) where my combo contained an enumeration in keyvalue pairs.

The ONLY way I could get the enumeration out was by

```
 KeyValuePair<string,string> selectedPair =  (KeyValuePair<string,string>)(cmbApplications.SelectedItem);
 ProTraceLicence.Products chosenProduct = (ProTraceLicence.Products)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProTraceLicence.Products), selectedPair.Key);
```

Hope this helps someone. Can't believe it's so difficult